# installing rdkit and deepchem on anaconda

Tags: python, rdkit

I am confused on how to install rdkit and deepchem.  Here I am listing the problems I am having and I appreciate your help.

rdkit:
After several trials, I finally figured out rdkit is only available on python2.  Following the recommendation on their site, I installed rdkit:

```
$ conda create -n rdkit -c rmg rdkit
$ source activate rdkit
```

I made sure the rdkit is successfully installed as I got the right version  when invoking from the terminal window:

```
>>> rdkit.__version__
'2016.03.4'
```

However, when I open the jupyet notebook, and import the rdkit, I got the error:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-6b72bd8913ab> in <module>()
----> 1 import rdkit

ImportError: No module named rdkit
```

deepchem:
I then went ahead and installed deepchem but because of dependency to rdkit I can't install deep chem.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple suggestions:

- Try using the one-liner DeepChem install command `conda install -c deepchem -c rdkit -c conda-forge -c omnia deepchem=2.3.0`. This will install rdkit in the same environment for you automatically.
- If your environment and rdkit are having trouble, I'd recommend using Google colab. This will allow you to experiment without having to deal with local installation issues https://forum.deepchem.io/t/getting-deepchem-running-in-colab/81

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not really using the conda environment to run the jupyter notebook. To verify this is the case, run in the terminal window and also insert in the jupyter notebook the following code:

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

In my case, I was running a python script and I got
Terminal window

> ['', '/home/sputnik/.conda/envs/compchem/lib/python310.zip',
> '/home/sputnik/.conda/envs/compchem/lib/python3.10',
> '/home/sputnik/.conda/envs/compchem/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload',
> '/home/sputnik/.conda/envs/compchem/lib/python3.10/site-packages']

Script run `./script.py`

> ['/home/sputnik', '/usr/lib/python38.zip',
> '/usr/lib/python3.8', '/usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload',
> '/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages',
> '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']

In my case the solution was to run the script explicitly calling python

```
python ./script.py
```

In the case of a Jupyter Notebook you will need to make sure it is running in the correct environment. You can use this package to help:

```
pip install environment_kernels
```

And get more information from:

http://stuartmumford.uk/blog/jupyter-notebook-and-conda.html